# Call a Python Script from parallel shell scripts at the same time

Tags: python, linux, shell

I have a question about the Python Interpreter. How does is treat the same script running 100 times, for example with different `sys.argv` entries? Does it create a different memory space for each script or something different?

System is Linux , CentOS 6.5. Is there any operational limit that can be observed and tuned?

Comment: I don't think Python will be the thing that limits you, but rather the OS (I'm thinking of ulimit and such)

Comment: I'm not sure what question you're asking here. Are you asking about how a python script can be called from multiple shell scripts concurrently (only the OS limits you I believe) or what happens when there are different arguments provided to a script? Could you clarify your question? Thank you.

Comment: What happens when you call same python script multiple times with different sys.argv elements. For example assume that you run this script in a for loop from shell like bellow  "  for i in `cat file` do; src_python.py $i &; done "   Just a random example for you to understand my question better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You won't have any problem with what you're trying to do. You can call the same script in parallel a lot of times, with different input arguments. (`sys.argv` entries). For each run, a new memory space will be allocated.